# how to use string variable as filter condition in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this:

```
cond <- "cyl == 4"
mtcars %>% filter_(cond)
```

which throws warning messege:

> filter_() is deprecated. 
>   Please use filter() instead

The problem is that I have no idea how to do the same thing with filter() function.

I'm using quoting and unquoting functions with select/mutate, but it seems they only work on columns. How to quote the logical condition?

Comment: Where are you getting the condition from? You should generally *not* attempt to perform such operations using strings, R has better ways of performing dynamic operations. Of course you can *parse* such a string as shown in Ronak’s answer but this is conceptually convoluted and has implications for performance and security.

Comment: it's for my own usage. Trying to build report from data with some basic set of instructions - from an excel file for start. More for learning purposes. But I'm sure interested in other ways of collecting instructions if you can give me some links

Comment: The general way for dealing with this is to create expressions, see the [tidyeval tutorial](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/). However, your described use-case probably benefits from using strings in the way you’re doing it, so carry on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `rlang::parse_expr` with `eval`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% filter(eval(rlang::parse_expr(cond)))

#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#2  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#3  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#4  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#5  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#6  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#7  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#8  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#9  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#10 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#11 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Or using `eval` and `parse`

```
mtcars %>% filter(eval(parse(text = cond)))
```

Comment: thanks. What about when I have 2 conditions, lets say i want to arrange result by gear and carb, so my string is "gear, carb". How to use this string in arrange function to get the same as with mtcars %>% arrange(gear, carb)

Comment: @h1427096 Actually, this isn't the right way to pass parameters. You can use `arrange_at` here. Assume you have `string <- "gear,carb"` you can then do `mtcars %>% arrange_at(strsplit(string, ",")[[1]])`

Comment: thanks, but I have also formulas in my strings, like: "wt > 5, hp" (sort by hp, but list those with wt > 5 at the end). Maybe I should open another question for this one. Right now I arrange conditions one by one backwards.

Comment: Yes, probably better to open a new question explaining detailed possibilities string can take and how you want to process them.

Comment: already got the answer. !!!rlang::parse_exprs(expr) did the trick